# How to set render value of coloum in VF page on basic of custom setting values

Tags: visualforce, customsetting

I have custom setting( with ORG wide default as  Profiles names like (system Admin, ReadOnly.) with comma delimted value.

```
<apex:column headerValue="myValue" rendered="{$setup.profilescustomsetting__c.getInstance().ByPassingProfiles__c.split(Pattern.quote(',').contains($Profile.Name)}">
```

Its not working.

Comment: "It's not working" is never enough to define a question. You cannot call arbitrary Apex methods in a Visualforce expression.

Comment: Thanks David, Can you please suggest if there is any other way to control that field. I have custom setting named profilescustomsetting__c,  and has ByPassingProfiles__c as field. I have defined three values System Admin stater, Readonly in that with comma deliemter. I would like to hide this column if those profile are there.

Comment: Please review @sfdcfox's excellent answer, which I think covers what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Visualforce uses a "formula" syntax, not an "Apex Code" syntax. What you're really looking for is something like:

```
{!CONTAINS($Setup.profilescustomsetting__c.bypassingprofiles__c,$Profile.Name)}
```

Or possibly even:

```
{!REGEX($Setup.profilescustomsetting__c.bypassingprofiles__c,',?'&$Profile.Name&',?')}
```

That said, use a [Custom Permission](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/custom_perms_overview.htm). That's what custom permissions where *designed* to do. That simplifies your code to just:

```
rendered="{!$Permission.Can_Do_Something}"
```

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox. I really appreciate it. Could you please tell me will !CONTAINS($Setup.profilescustomsetting__c.bypassingprofiles__c,$Profile.Name) search in both values of custom setting as i  have values like. SystemAdmin, Readonly ( as comma delimiter )

Comment: I want if SystemAdmin, or ReadyOnly access that page, then only that coloum appear

Comment: @DavidMycka The CONTAINS operator checks if the first text contains the second text. Look at the [formula reference](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions.htm&type=5) for more details. Mind you, if you want it so that the column disappears when the profile is listed, you probably meant to say you want `{!NOT(CONTAINS(...))}` instead.